# Bayesian AB Testing: Simulated vs analytically derived posterior

Tags: bayesian, naive-bayes

Consider the problem of distributing two leaflets A and B to increase sales of a given product. We distribute 20 of leaflet A (with 8 successes) and 20 of leaflet B (with 3 successes). We know want to know what the probability is that leaflet A is better than leaflet B.

We can do this in two ways, the first is simulation. Using for example a uniform distribution as a prior which we sample our binomial parameter p from. Or alternatively, through utilising the fact that the beta distribution is a conjugate prior of the binomial. As such we can just perturb our initial prior configuration (likely to be Beta(1,1) as it is the same a uniform distribution) by the data to obtain our posterior.

If i want to now calculate "the probability is that leaflet A is better than leaflet B"

I have read [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130331072458/http://arsatiki.posterous.com/bayesian-ab-testing-with-theory-and-code) that i can do this by:

> First, generate N pairs of random samples from the joint distribution.
>   Since they are independent, you need only pick the first item in the
>   pair from the first beta distribution and similarly for the second
>   item. You may need to generate a lot of samples, if the two rates are
>   close to each other. Count how many of the pairs have the first number
>   greater than the second. Let us call this number k. Then you can get
>   the estimate for the probability P(r₁ > r₂) simply dividing k / N.

This makes sense for the analytically derived example but can i extend it to the simulated example.

In other words can I randomly draw pairs of values from the two simulated distributions for A and B, compare their values (repeat a few thousand times) and the resulting tally will be the answer to my questions?

Thanks in advance, happy to clarify if needed

Edit: The simulated case (sampling the parameter of the binomial distribution (p) from a uniform prior):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The two leaflets are independent, so we can examine their posteriors independently.

Leaflet A has a posterior of

$$ p_A \sim \operatorname{Beta}(8+1, 12+1) $$

Leaflet B has a posterior of

$$ p_B \sim \operatorname{Beta}(3+1, 17+1) $$

We can compute the probability that $p_A>p_B$ by just simulating from these distributions and comparing element by element if our draw from A's posterior is larger than the draw from B's posterior.

```r
set.seed(0)
pa = rbeta(1000, 9, 13)
pb = rbeta(1000, 4, 18)

mean(pa>pb)
>>>0.953
```

This means that 95.3% of the draws from A's posterior were larger than the draws from B's posterior.  This, we estimate $P(p_A>p_B) = 0.953$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I realise that but what if instead of using the fact that the beta is conjugate to the binomial I used simulation? Could i just randomly draw pairs and compare them in the same way as is done for the conjugate case?

Comment: I have added what the simulated case looks like (I have done the conjugate case also - the distributions look largely identical).